# Solving a reaction diffusion equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJAJT.png)

Sorry guys i really need some help on this one. 
If i have a PDE $U_t = U_{xx} + U - U^3$ which is equal to $U_t = - \nabla  E(U)$

with $E(U) = \int \frac{1}{2}U_x^2 + \frac{1}{4}(U^2 - 1)^2$

If I use a implicit Euler $U_t$ replaced by $\frac{U_n - U_{n-1}}{k}$

I have to prove that :
$$
E(U_n) + \left|\frac{U_n - U_{n-1}}{2k}\right|_1 < E(U_{n-1})
$$

Comment: Pepe can you check the equations. I have tried to help you a bit here, as the question may be interesting.

Comment: Yes this is the right problem asked